# How to delete documents from mongodb using python code

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

I am trying to delete documents from my local mongodb collection using python code based on certain condition. I am getting the error TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'delete_many' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

I tried using find_one_and_delete, but no luck. Can some one tell me where am I going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```py
import sys
import os

import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient


def _get_data(db, name):   
    my_count = db[name].find().count()
    print ("Record count in", name, my_count)
    my_cursor = db[name].find().sort("save_date")

    for data in my_cursor:   
       if condition1 and condition2: 
            deleted_records = db[name].delete_many({ "_id" : data['_id']}, {"project_id" : 100})   
            print(data['_id'], data['project_id'],data['save_date'], "record for deletion")

    print("No records found for deletion")



if __name__ == '__main__':

    connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = connection['TEST']
    collection_names = [ list of collection names..]
    for name in collection_names:
       _get_data(db,"mycollection")
```

I am able to print the documents but not able to delete them.

Comment: Thank you. But,that didn't work for me either

Answer (score 0):

remove() function worked for me. Hope this helps someone who is new to mongodb like me :)

deleted_records = db[name].remove({"_id" : data['_id'], "project_id" : 100})